# Is it possible to do row wise matrix multiplication is numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Suppose I have the following two arrays:

```
X = np.array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.]])

B = np.array([[2, 4, 6],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```

I want to compute a row wise matrix multiplication such that the output is:

`y = np.array([28, 28, 28, 28])`, i.e. each element in y is something like `np.array([1, 2, 3]) dot np.array([2, 4, 6]) = 28`

Is this possible?

Comment: `y = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', X, B)` or `y = (X*B).sum(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You may try transposing your matrix.

```
X = np.array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.]])

B = np.array([[2, 4, 6],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [2, 4, 6]])

y = (X @ B.T).T
```